# Resolve Anaconda/iPython Notebooks/Spyder IDE launch failure on zmq lib import?

Tags: python, ide, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

This is a fresh Anaconda 2.1 install on Windows 7 - 64, python 2.7.8 . The Spyder IDE fails to launch, and throws the same error/writes same traceback when `python spyder --reset` is run from cli. Looking at the traceback, it appears to be a problem loading `zmq` module. That module's `\__init__.py` looks for any precompiled `libzmq` file with one of these exts: `pyd`, `so`, `dll`, `dylib`, and adds them to list `bundled`, and then tries to load `bundled[0]`.

```
bundled = []
bundled_sodium = []
for ext in ('pyd', 'so', 'dll', 'dylib'):
    bundled_sodium.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(here, 'libsodium*.%s*' % ext)))
    bundled.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(here, 'libzmq*.%s*' % ext)))
```

The confusing thing is that `libzmq.pyd` is located right in the `Anaconda2.1\Lib\site-packages\zmq` directory! After looking both at code and at the other questions on SO, I'm stumped. Please help.

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\someUser>cmd /K spyder
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 2, in <m
    odule>
        start_app.main()
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py
    ", line 85, in main
        from spyderlib import spyder
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py",
    line 45, in <module>
        from spyderlib.ipythonconfig import IPYTHON_QT_INSTALLED, SUPPORTED_IPYTHON
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\ipythonconfi
    g.py", line 22, in <module>
        IPYTHON_QT_INSTALLED = is_qtconsole_installed()
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\ipythonconfi
    g.py", line 15, in is_qtconsole_installed
        pyzmq_installed = programs.is_module_installed('zmq')
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\progra
    ms.py", line 272, in is_module_installed
        actver = get_module_version(module_name)
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\progra
    ms.py", line 218, in get_module_version
        mod = __import__(module_name)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
        _libzmq = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled[0])
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in Lo
    adLibrary
        return self._dlltype(name)
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __
    init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

    C:\Users\someUser>spyder --reset
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 2, in <m
    odule>
        start_app.main()
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\start_app.py
    ", line 85, in main
        from spyderlib import spyder
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\spyder.py",
    line 45, in <module>
        from spyderlib.ipythonconfig import IPYTHON_QT_INSTALLED, SUPPORTED_IPYTHON
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\ipythonconfi
    g.py", line 22, in <module>
        IPYTHON_QT_INSTALLED = is_qtconsole_installed()
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\ipythonconfi
    g.py", line 15, in is_qtconsole_installed
        pyzmq_installed = programs.is_module_installed('zmq')
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\progra
    ms.py", line 272, in is_module_installed
        actver = get_module_version(module_name)
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\utils\progra
    ms.py", line 218, in get_module_version
        mod = __import__(module_name)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
        _libzmq = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled[0])
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in Lo
    adLibrary
        return self._dlltype(name)
      File "C:\Users\someUser\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __
    init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

EDIT: This issue is also preventing iPython Notebooks from opening. Identical error in traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eric.adams\Anaconda2.1\Scripts/ipython-script.py", line 5, in <
module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_i
python
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 563,
in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 92, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in i
nitialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 92, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 381, in
 initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in p
arse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 92, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 475,
in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 92, i
n catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 406,
in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42, i
n import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 39, in
<module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 35, in
check_for_zmq
    import zmq
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled[0])
  File "C:\Users\eric.adams\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in Lo
adLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\eric.adams\Anaconda2.1\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __
init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are picking up an install of Python in `C:\Python27` somehow. Do you have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set?  If so, unset it.

The easiest solution is to just delete or set aside `C:\Python27`.